# WordPress permalink gives 404 after copy paste

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I'm using utf8 urls (Hebrew) and encountered a weird behavior.

Reaching the website and browsing between pages works perfectly.
But copying the url and pasting it to a different tab will get you to a 404 page.

Also all links that are indexed by google shows 404 errors
This problem occurs only on the woo-commerce category links and i should mention that im using a plugin to remove the category base from the url.

How can i solve this ?
You can view the behavior on http://thj.360.co.il/

Answer (score 0):

You may need to update your permalink structure again in settings. Just save the page again so it updates htaccess.

Comment: anyway you can see that if you use the links in the menu it is working fine, the problem only occurs when you copy/paste the url and on google search results. i believe it has something to do with the encoding but i don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Pay attention that the link in hebrew parsed differently from the link that works:

WORKING LINK:
http://thj.360.co.il/%d7%98%d7%91%d7%a2%d7%95%d7%aa-%d7%99%d7%94%d7%9c%d7%95%d7%9e%d7%99%d7%9d/

NOT WORKING LINK:
http://thj.360.co.il/%D7%98%D7%91%D7%A2%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%99%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D/

As you see in the second link all the letters are capitalized...